# Mysql Master Master Replication

Tags: mysql, database-replication, mysql-error-1045

Server1: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

```
server-id=1 
binlog-do-db=sample 
master-host = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
master-user = someuser 
master-password = somepassword 
master-connect-retry = 60 
relay-log = /var/lib/mysql/slave-relay.log 
relay-log-index = /var/lib/mysql/slave-relay-log.index
```

Server 2: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

```
server-id=2 
binlog-do-db = sample 
master-host = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
master-user = someuser 
master-password = somepassword 
master-connect-retry = 60 
relay-log = /var/lib/mysql/slave-relay.log 
relay-log-index = /var/lib/mysql/slave-relay-log.index
```

I have setup the master master replication configuration on 2 test servers, i have also opened ports for both the mysql 3306 on servers i am facing a problem with slave connection I keep getting the

following errors 101021 19:12:23 [ERROR] Slave I/O: error connecting to master 'root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306' - retry-time: 60 retries: 86400, Error_code: 1045

Sever 1 has mysql 5.0.77 and server 2 has mysql version 5.1.41

Comment: What happens when you `telnet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 3306` from one server to another? Also, you'll want to set up autoincrement offsets.

Answer (score 6):

Error_code: 1045 means that there is a problem with your credentials.

Try to connect with your replication user credentials like :

```
mysql -h host -u your_user -p your_password
```

Note that the password is limited to 32 characters.

Comment: You sir saved my life. I've been searching for _hours_ why on earth my replication did not work. Turns out my password was 50 chars long… I **HATE** MySQL more than ever now (never liked it anyway… PostGres FTW!)

Comment: F*ck, I have spent 2 hours of my life, retried whole process from the beginning few times... Thank you!